# Using zeromq to design a publish subscribe system with multiple brokers

Tags: zeromq, publish-subscribe

I started with zeromq just a few days ago. My aim is to design a publish subscribe system with multiple brokers (a network of brokers). I have read the relevant sections of the zeromq guide, and have written code for simple pub sub systems. If someone could please help me with the following questions:

From what I can conceive, the brokers(xpub-xsub sockets) will  also have push/pull sockets to communicate the pub-sub messages. Is that correct? Any help in terms of **how the brokers should communicate** would be appreciated. Should there be any intermediaries between brokers?

Any design guidelines would be very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> The guide says that we should use xpub and xsub sockets when dynamic
>   discovery is required. Can someone please explain the difference
>   between the sockets: xpub and pub, and xsub and sub.

`XPUB` just means many publishers , compared to `PUB`, which means single publisher.

`XSUB` means many subscribers, compared to `SUB`, meaning single subscriber.

If you want to connect many subscribers to many publishers while still having the benefit dynamic discovery, you need a proxy in the middle; something like illustration below. PUB sockets sending messages to a proxy; the XSUB forwards message to XPUB, which then distributes those messages to all SUBs listening.

The code for creating such a proxy is simple (below), and the PUB and SUB ends are trivial, check the example [code](https://github.com/imatix/zguide/tree/master/examples/).

```java
Socket xsub = ctx.createSocket(ZMQ.XSUB);
input.bind( "tcp://*:5500");            
Socket xpub = ctx.createSocket(ZMQ.XPUB);
xpub.bind( "tcp://*:5600");
ZMQ.proxy( xsub, xpub, null);
```

[image]

> From what I can conceive, the brokers will also have push/pull sockets
>   to communicate the pub-sub messages. Is that correct? Any help in
>   terms of how the brokers should communicate would be appreciated.
>   Should there be any intermediaries between brokers?

Check the guide for [Inter-Broker Routing](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Worked-Example-Inter-Broker-Routing) example

Comment: The Inter-Broker routing examples are helpful, but I need help to understand the following in detail: 1. what should be the logical topology of the broker network. 2. how would they know about each other to begin with? 3. how to do the routing of the published messages all the way to the right subscriber?  Such questions are clouding my mind, and I really don't know where to start. Even for a small prototype with 4-5 brokers, and a few publishers/subscribers, I feel that I have to answer these questions. Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: I had the same questions, and the best advice I can give you is to start small with examples (https://github.com/imatix/zguide/tree/master/examples/); each one addresses a different use case, once you understand them, you can build complex messaging systems.

Comment: Did this help you out at all?

Comment: Yes, it did. I started to design a request-reply system using the inter-broker routing example, and the majordomo pattern. Pub-sub needs to be added later on. For a small number of brokers, it works well, but since all the brokers know each other, the system is quite chatty. I am still not sure how to do the routing for a large number of brokers. There are some hints about using a Distributed Hash Table, but I am still thinking about it. Any ideas?